# Combine string with JSON.stringify (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

Ok, this question may be dumb, but I'm really stuck with this.

I want to a json structure like the following:

```
order: {
    currency: 'eur',
    order_items: [
        {
            id: 3,
            quantity: 1
        },
        {
            id: 67,
            quantity: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm doing right now is this:

```
function makeOrder(){
    var myArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<bookedItemsArray.length;i++){
        var newObject = new OrderedItem(bookedItemsArray[i].id, bookedItemsArray[i].amount);
        myArray.push(newObject);
    }
    var mystring = JSON.stringify(myArray);
    //myString = "order: {currency: 'eur', order_items: " + myString + "}";
    console.log(myString);​
}
```

The way I get the data inside the order_items array is being cool, but when I try to concat the array with the rest (line in comments), I get:

```
?:??: W/?(?): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at file:///android_asset/www/november/js/t03/Booking/bookingProcess.js:96
```

Is there something I'm missing about the way a string and a JSON structure can be combined?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It’s difficult to understand the acutal question, please explain "concat the array with the rest (line in comments)".

Comment: Concatenating two valid JSON strings won't create a valid JSON strings (unless they both describe a number)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myArray)` should always produce a valid JSON string unless the argument cannot be encoded.

Comment: Check variable name: mystring vs myString.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you should write an answer

Comment: The error message indicates you have a syntax error in your code and out of our sight.

Comment: Ok, @YuriTarabanko was right. I was having this difference between mystring and myString (God...), but anyway the error persists. Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you do it like this?

```
var x = {
    order: {
        currency: 'eur',
        order_items: []
    }
};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var newObject = {
        i: i,
        Text: 'Some Text'
    };
    x.order.order_items.push(newObject);
}

var str = JSON.stringify(x);
```

look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9V6Vb/

Here is the generated JSON:

```
{
    "order": {
        "currency": "eur",
        "order_items": [{
            "i": 0,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 1,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 2,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 3,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 4,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 5,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 6,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 7,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 8,
            "Text": "Some Text"},
        {
            "i": 9,
            "Text": "Some Text"}]
    }
}​
```

Comment: Fixed the typo, but if I understand right, he is trying to do some string concatenation to get the final JSON representation. What he should do (in my opinion) is construct the full object and stringify that.

Comment: He definitely should. I even think he does.

Comment: This solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot, @Raiden.

Answer (score 0):

JSON should be encapsulated in `{` and `}`.

So your JSON probably should be like:

```
{
    "order": {
        "currency": "eur",
        "order_items": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 67,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse("[]")` returns an array. `JSON.parse("{a:1}")` throws an exception.

Comment: @JanDvorak You're right, updated my answer so all properties are between quotes.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` is still valid JSON

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"order": {"currency": "eur", "order_items": [{"id": 3,"quantity": 1},{"id": 67,"quantity": 1}]}}')` is valid

Comment: As is `JSON.parse('[1,2,3]')`, so there need not be any curly brackets in valid JSON.

Comment: If the top level object is an array, there is no need to wrap it in another object so that the outermost brackets curl.

Comment: Of course, if you're talking about best practice... then this answer is still irrelevant (and void - OP does wrap the JSON in curly braces). Sorry.

Comment: Just tried to say there is a difference between object literals and JSON. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ for more info about JSON/object literals.

Comment: I can agree with the last statement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As Koen say it, you can make an object with first property is order and stringify all object in one time.

```
var myOrder = {
order: {
currency: 'eur',
         order_items: [
           {
             id: 3,
             quantity: 1
           },
           {
             id: 67,
             quantity: 1
           }
         ]
      }
}
console.log("currency : " + myOrder.order.currency);
for (var i in myOrder.order.order_items) {
    console.log("items number " + i);
    console.log("items id" + myOrder.order.order_items[i].id);
    console.log("items quantity" + myOrder.order.order_items[i].quantity);
}
var myString = JSON.stringify(myOrder);
console.log(myString);
```

but I think you should make "order" your object direcly

Regards,